# How to show Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD' in red and green color

Tags: html, css

I would like to show Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD' in red and green color.
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0023FA/index.htm

This is my html with css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div color="red">⚫</div>
  <div color="red">&#x23FA</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I dont get expected result

Any suggestion how to fix this?
Result:
https://jsfiddle.net/y8uz25Lv/

[image]

Comment: Large Red Circle  &#x1f534; - is that ok?

Comment: @mplungjn yes, nice. And what if I want to have green?

Comment: the amount of downvoted answers is astonishing. What's happening lmao

Comment: @ZombieChowder Apparently nobody tests their code before posting.

Comment: @Turnip am also a bit lost here ... what is the intended result, a red cirlce, right?

Comment:  - for green ;))))

Comment: &#127817; Try this if you need green **AND** red.

Comment: It would probably be easier just to create a circle with `border-radius`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't technically possible.

The horrible hack is to hide the emoji itself and show a shadow instead.

```css
.red {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">⚫</div>
```

**Warning**: This will destroy the shading on the emoji as a side effect.

---

A better solution would probably be to use a more appropriate character (such as U+2B24) in the first place.

```css
.red    { color: red; }
.yellow { color: yellow; }
.green  { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="red">⬤</div>
<div class="yellow">⬤</div>
<div class="green">⬤</div>
```

Comment: Finally a real answer ;)))

Comment: Isn't 2B24  ⬤ also a black circle?

Comment: @mplungjan — It has the world *black* in the name, but it isn't a character that comes with colour information.

Comment: Thanks. In my case is even better with bootstrap class: <div class="text-danger">⬤</div>
<div class="text-success">⬤</div>. Then I don't have to write custom css. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/78628/

Answer (score 0):

https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%9A%AB/

Its a Black Circle. You can´t colorize it.

Use  &#x1f534